# Code which checks file size of video using download link before downloading? [edited]

Tags: python, python-3.x, sys, python-webbrowser

I was reading the book 'Automating the boring stuff with python' where I read about webbrowser module. I tried to make a program that downloads a given number of videos from the web. But since Chrome starts multiple downloads simultaneously, I wondered if there could be some code which could replace the comments in my code listed below.

```
# This is a program to download a list of episodes

import webbrowser, sys

start = int(sys.argv[1])  # denotes the starting episode number    
stop = int(sys.argv[2])  # denotes the final episode number

while start <= stop:
    link = #(first half of link) + str(start) + #(final half of link)
    #here goes the code that checks the size of the video to be downloaded
    webbrowser.open(link)
    while True:
        # here goes an if statement that keeps checking the size of the downloaded file
            start += 1
            break
        else:
            continue
```

Edit 1:

I have deduced a part of my original question which repeatedly checks the downloaded size. However, the code which actually lets me know of the file size before downloading is still out of my knowledge

```
# This is a program to download a list of episodes

import webbrowser, sys, os

start = int(sys.argv[1])  # denotes the starting episode number    
stop = int(sys.argv[2])  # denotes the final episode number

while start <= stop:
    link = #(first half of link) + str(start) + #(final half of link)
    file = #name under which video will be downloaded
    os.chdir(r'C:\Users\OWNER\Downloads')
    #here goes the code that checks the size of the video to be downloaded
    webbrowser.open(link)
    while True:
        if os.path.getsize(file) >= # size of file to be downloaded:
            start += 1
            break
        else:
            continue
```